# how to connect to WebSocket without context manager?

Tags: python, websocket

I want to work with the WebSockets package that the documentation says I can connect to WebSocket like this :

```
    async with WebSockets.connect(URI) as WebSocket:
          greeting = await WebSocket.recv()
```

but i want to connect without context manager but i got error :

```
ws = websockets.connect(uri)
msg = ws.recv()
```

here is the error :

```
AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'recv'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you want to connect without context manager?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard because I want to keep the connection as a variable because I need to have control over WebSocket outside of context manager like was. close()

Comment: You should be able to put all your code inside the `with`, using functions if needed for a cleaner code. If you use the context manager, you don't need to close the websocket yourself, that's the purpose of the context manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the context manager does not exempt you from using `async`/`await`.

```
ws = await websockets.connect(uri)
try:
    msg = await ws.recv()
finally:   # If you don't use context manager, you have to close the connection manually
    await ws.ws_client.close()
```

But I don't see any reason not to use the context manager. If you remove it, you have to replace it with a `try`/`finally` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this, I made the same mistake as OP - namely, not `await`ing the call to `websockets.connect`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `ws.close()`. Without it the event loop will never end. For the necessity of avoiding context manager, there are scenarios where it needs a connection pool; there are also scenarios where `ws` is passed to another module and you lose control of its life cycle.